# Detect if Wear OS device is connected to iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, bluetooth, connection, wear-os

Is there a way to determine if my Android watches are connected to an android phone or an iPhone?

We have a business case do differs between these two cases and use [PKCE](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/auth-wear#pkce) for android and [DAG](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/auth-wear#DAG) authorization flow for iPhones.
I want to know when to apply each flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [PhoneTypeHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/wear/phone/interactions/PhoneTypeHelper):

```kotlin
PhoneTypeHelper.getPhoneDeviceType(context) == PhoneTypeHelper.DEVICE_TYPE_IOS
```

More info in [Details for detecting the type of paired phone](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/standalone-apps.html#get-phone-type).